# Improving Full Text Search MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have a search engine based site that is currently in beta mode http://www.jobportfolio.co.uk. The site has a job table that incorporates the following fields, (job_company, job_title, job_description, job_location) all the fields are Var except for description that is a text field. All the fields are indexed as FullText.

My current approach is to search based on the title, location and company. This seems to work fine however I would like to improve the search results by adding in the description field. The problem is however when I add the description field the search seems to take a lot longer. Even with a table that only contains 12000 rows it seems to be slow.

I am using the following MATCH AGAINST query to select the results

```
MATCH(job_posts.job_title, job_company) AGAINST('".$this->mysqli_escape($job_title)."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Does anyone have any opinions on how to improve the performance of the search?

Comment: do you have one single fulltext index that covers those fields, or multiple fulltext indexes that cover some/part of the fields?

Comment: Also, there are more options than just `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.

Comment: I use PHPMYADMIN and have an fulltext index for each of the fields seperately. Is it better to have one index to cover them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, my first thought is to approach this problem from the "outside": is it acceptable to have a search form that uses multiple different fields? If you're willing to have 4 search strings that each search in a different column, I suspect that will reduce load by itself. For example:

When someone types in the "location" field, you add a clause to the query that matches the searched text against the location field only.

When someone types in the "description" field, you add a clause to the query that matches the search text against the description field. Otherwise you don't match anything against the description field.

If you don't need to be able to enter text into one place and search "all possible fields" for it, this solution will prevent extra slowness until someone specifically wants to search in the description text. So the query speed varies based on the searcher's needs.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. At the minute there are 2 form fields currently if you search the location it will only search a location field. If the description field is complete it will search the other fields.

Comment: Yes. But I understood the SQL snippet you quoted above,  `MATCH(job_posts.job_title, job_company) AGAINST('{$string}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`, to mean that the string you entered would be simultaneously compared against all the fields listed. In many contexts this is necessary, and a search wouldn't make sense without doing so; but performance will suffer if the default is to always search all fields.