# Mysql key_buffer_size already 16GB but some fulltext searches are still slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a query w/ full text search which takes 5 - 10 secs. key_buffer_size is already 16GB.
Table has **15 million records** and has a compound fulltext index on fields: categories and company.

Table Size:
Data Length - 0.9GB
Index Length - 1.1GB

```
    SELECT c.id FROM basetable c 
    WHERE MATCH(c.categories, c.company) 
    AGAINST('+keyword1 +keyword2 +keyword3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    LIMIT 100
```

**Query Results**:
only 88 rows

**Query Status**:
Key_read_requests - 4414336
Key_reads - 1029
Key_write_requests - 12
Key_writes - 2
Handler_read_next - 89

**Mysql Global Variables**:
key_buffer_size - **16GB**
key_cache_age_threshold - 300
key_cache_block_size - 1024
key_cache_division_limit - 100
max_heap_table_size - 6gb
tmp_table_size - 6gb

**Server:**
Dual XEONS CPUs
32GB RAM
HD 15kRPM.

Note that not all queries are slow. Some are less than a second; it depends on the keywords used on Full Text search.

Do you have any thoughts on how to improve this?

Comment: John, please take a look on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804785/improving-full-text-search-mysql

Comment: Thanks! I also have a search engine based site. But the idea is to be something like Google search. The categories field contains all category (CSV); it is still slow even when I remove the name.

Comment: Have you ever tried Solr? Maybe it worth a look at.  =)

Comment: What are your innodb values in config ?

Comment: for example : innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M, innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 32M

Comment: I am using Myisam tables.

Comment: Last option for me is to try Sphinx, Solr, etc.